# I have a div that I need to stay in a certain position when the screen gets smaller

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently having a problem with a div on my site. I'm trying to get it to stay in a fixed position even on smaller resolutions but no matter what I have tried so far the div moves to the right every time the window gets smaller.

Here are pictures of the issue:

**Correct position:**

[image]

**Incorrect position:**

[image]

Also, here is the CSS for the div:

```
#fep-notification-bar{
    color: #f3ed42;
    border-width: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #282828;
    margin-left: 1338px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

The site is wastelandgamers.com

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue I would really appreciate it!

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I wasn't clear enough and I realize now that the way I clipped the pictures makes it seem like the header is expanding but that's not the case. The new message text is what won't won't stay in place. whenever I make the screen smaller the text moves to the right instead of staying in place above the search bar. Unfortunately you can't really test it unless you are logged in and get a message.

Comment: Looks to work just fine when I visit your site. Check that the "you have 1 unread message" html isn't messing up the positioning (ie delete it in web inspector). As someone who isn't logged in that line when I visit the site isn't there. Otherwise, try fixed positioning your search by.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough and I realize now that the way I clipped the pictures makes it seem like the header is expanding but that's not the case. The new message text is what won't won't stay in place. whenever I make the screen smaller the text moves to the right instead of staying in place above the search bar. Unfortunately you can't really test it unless you are logged in and get a message.

Comment: Ahh I see, my bad. I thought you were referring to the input moving not the text!

Comment: Not your fault, I definitely clipped it poorly in highndsight haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a solution for now. I have changed the code to:

```
#fep-notification-bar{
    color: #f3ed42;
    border-width: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    margin-left: 24.7%;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
}
```

It has not completely solved my problem but it is at least a band-aid. This way the text still moves slightly, however, it now moves to the left and only a small amount so it does not fall off the page no matter how small it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your HTML looks like but from the screenshots I would wrap all the elements up in a span or div and then position that.

Comment: I am trying to find my HTML file but can't seem to figure out where they are located on wordpress. I have looked through my file manager everywhere and can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use float:right maybe then edit certain classes or ids using @media in the css.

Comment: Will try this now.